# codiegniter file uploading taking lot of time to upload on server

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, upload, codeigniter-3

i have a codeigniter website where there is a form with few fields and multi image upload option, user can upload upto 4 images at a time, the images are resized and uploaded to server, my controller is like below:

```html
if(isset($_POST['addproduct']))
{



$this->form_validation->set_rules('productname', 'Product Name', 'required|trim|is_unique[product.productname]');




$this->load->library('upload');
$image = array();
$ImageCount = count($_FILES['pimage']['name']);
for($i = 0; $i < $ImageCount; $i++){ $_FILES['file']['name']=$_FILES['pimage']['name'][$i];
    $_FILES['file']['type']=$_FILES['pimage']['type'][$i];
    $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']=$_FILES['pimage']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $_FILES['file']['error']=$_FILES['pimage']['error'][$i]; $_FILES['file']['size']=$_FILES['pimage']['size'][$i]; //
    File upload configuration $uploadPath=DOC_ROOT.'admin/uploads/products/'; $config['upload_path']=$uploadPath;
    $config['allowed_types']='jpg|jpeg|png|gif' ; // Load and initialize upload library $this->load->library('upload',
    $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    // Upload file to server
    if($this->upload->do_upload('file')){
    // Uploaded file data
    $imageData = $this->upload->data();
    // $uploadImgData[$i]['image_name'] = $imageData['file_name'];
    $uploadImgData[] = $imageData['file_name'];


    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    $path=$data['upload_data']['full_path'];
    $q['name']=$data['upload_data']['file_name'];

    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = $path;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width'] = 1000;
    $config['height'] = 1000;

    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();

    unset($config);
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $this->image_lib->clear();




    }
    }






    $productname = $this->input->post('productname');

  


    $mrp = $this->input->post('mrp');
    $vrp = $this->input->post('vrp');
    $jrp = $this->input->post('jrp');

    $description = $this->input->post('description');
    $shortdesc = $this->input->post('shortdesc');

    $category = $this->input->post('category');
    $subcategory = $this->input->post('subcategory');

  

    $pimage = $uploadImgData;



    $insertUserData =
    $this->category->addproduct($productname,$mrp,$vrp,$jrp,$description,$shortdesc,$category,$subcategory,$pimage);

    if($insertUserData){
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'Product Addedd Successfuly');
    }else{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', 'Some problems occured, please try again.');
    }

    redirect('products');



    }
```

if i upload like 4 images above 10mb, the upload is taking like 3mins to complete and submit the form, can anyone please tell me what is wrong in here, thanks in advance